# regular pregmatch in preg_split

Tags: php

I want ask about preg_match how i can understand

```
/\s*;\s*/
```

In code

```
preg_split('/\s*;\s*/', $something);
```

I want know how i can replace preg_split I do not know, because I do not know meaning of the expression as a function of

Comment: what mean /\s*;\s*/ expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tha regex pattern `/\s*;\s*/`

The first and the last `/` are delimiters. And should always encapsulate the regex pattern (at least for `preg` functions).

You could also use another character for this, but `/` is often used.

Could have also written it like: `#\s*;\s*#`

The `\s` in the pattern matches white-space characters (space, tabs, linebreaks).

The `*` means repeats the previous item zero or more times.

The `;` is just the character `;`.

Also see the info @ http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for a cheatsheet

Comment: i can use string replace to do this ?

Comment: @zyeu: Whether you could do a `str_replace()` depends. The regex checks for white-space character(s). If the number of white-space characters are always the same and you know this on forehand you should use `str_replace()` since it is faster. Again it all depends on the format of the string.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Encode to what? @PeeHaa's answer helps you to undersrand this specific regex but if you want to write your own, you should read a reference/tutorial.